# Stripe sending money to user bank account

Tags: stripe-payments, stripes

I have built application that similar to to freelancer marketplace. I want to when user earn money thorugh my marketplace. A buyer only can pay using their card, which is already implemented with `stripe`

and a `seller` should be able to withdraw their money to direct their bank. But i didn't notice such a feature on the stripe.

I notice stripe `refund` method to refund funds, which i dont want, coz, i am not going to refund money to any user buyer. I just want to send the seller bank account directly from my stripe account

How can i do it?

I notice this, but i dont want it all

```
charge = await stripe.charges.refund(charge.id, {
amount: 1000
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to read about [Connect](https://stripe.com/connect), Stripe's product to help you [build marketplaces](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide) like you describe. Your seller would have a [connected account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/explore-connect-guide#account-types) and you'd send them money with [payouts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/bank-debit-card-payouts).